# does AVI RAW suppport sound in Blender?

Tags: file-format, audio

when I render my Blender Video Editor projects to AVI RAW, I don't get any sound in the output file.  I'm on version 2.78.5.

Comment: Then probably not. Why not use a more modern video container like Matroska (mkv)?

Answer (score 1):

Go to *File Format* and choose FFmpeg vid – this opens the proper encoding options.

Comment: Or choose Xvid and avi file extention.